# How to display a specific value in a Spinner

Tags: android

I am building an Inventory Management Application and one of the features is to be able to categorize the products. When the user creates a new product listing, they are able to select a category for that product through a `Spinner` (the `Spinner` is dynamically created by whatever categories they have added). However, I also want the user to later edit that product and be able to change its values (such as name, selling price etc.) including the ability to select a new category for the product. When they are presented with the screen for editting the product, all the appropriate components will be filled in already, for example, if I had an `EditText` for the name, then the name will appear there, where they can tap on it and edit it straight away. So my question is, how can I do the same for `Spinner`, where is the category's name is already selected from the possible choices?

For the category I can either obtain an `ArrayList` of `Strings` for their names or an `ArrayList` of `Category` objects and am quite flexible in that sense. I pasted below my Category object to give some context.

```
package com.example.fabricanddecor;

public class Category {

    private int id;
    private String categoryName;

    public Category()
    {}

    public Category(int id, String categoryName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spinner.setSelection(position);` to select the item in a spinner. All you need is to find the `position` of the item in the ArrayList.